# How to pass values during compilation with g++ using -DN flag

Tags: gcc, g++, compiler-flags

I've heard that you can set values in your c++ program during compilation using g++'s -DN flag. Can anybody explain how?
Thank you

Comment: have you read the man page for gcc?  if I google `man gcc` and search for `-D` (and understand the preprocessor), it seems quite clear

Answer (score 14):

`-DXXX` flag is just like adding `#define XXX`. So `-DN=2` is just like `#define N  2`.

And you can pass values during compilation using this flag.

Reference:

- [GCC Preprocessor Options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options)